# faster way to search column pairs in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a big dataframe called `df` around 45 million row like below. [download](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ydrVDE5mU9KHT8k9XybTjGInqdFg07R4?usp=sharing)

```
        gene1   gene2     score
0       PIGA  ATF7IP1 -0.047236
1       PIGB  ATF7IP2 -0.047236
2       PIGC  ATF7IP3 -0.047236
3       PIGD  ATF7IP4 -0.047236
4       PIGE  ATF7IP5 -0.047236
```

and I have a small dataframe called `terms`, size is around 3k row.

```
id                                gene_set
1                                 {HDAC4, BCL6}
2                                 {HDAC5, BCL6}
3                                 {HDAC7, BCL6}
4                 {NCOA3, KAT2B, EP300, CREBBP}
5            {NCAPD2, NCAPH, NCAPG, SMC4, SMC2}
                         ...                   
2912                              {FOXO1, ESR1}
2913                               {APP, FOXO3}
2914                               {APP, FOXO1}
2915                               {APP, FOXO4}
2916    {MAP3K20, MAPK14, AKAP13, MAP2K3, PKN1}
```

and for each row I check the presence of `gene1,gene2` pairs in the `terms` dataset.

my code works fine, but I would like to ask is there any **faster idea** to that?
I have tried couple of codes but the run time approximately is the same.

```
def search(g1,g2):
    # search gene pair in the go terms
    return sum(terms.gene_set.map(set([g1,g2]).issubset))
```

code example 1

```
np.sum(np.vectorize(search)(df.gene1,df.gene2))
```

code example 2

```
[search(g1, g2) for g1, g2 in zip(df.gene1,df.gene2)]
```

code example 3

```
df[['gene1','gene2']].apply(lambda x: search(x.gene1,x.gene2), axis=1 )
```

Comment: 45 million rows! I would seriously consider Polars over Pandas in this case

Comment: can you share a link to a csv file with a million records from your `df` and the file for `terms`? (for testing)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have added the download link for the df and terms.

Comment: also, what should happen with result (45 millions sums)? Is it expected to be inserted back into `df` as new column?

Comment: yes, It is expected to inserted as a new column to `df`. btw, sum of the records are not important it can be acceptable with boolen, exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

I see a clear way to speedup a bit your `search` function by modifying `set([g1,g2])` into `{g1,g2}.issubset`. You avoid quite a bit of work since there is no need to convert the list to a set anymore.

Here a simple test case

```
In [4]: %timeit set([1,2]).issubset({1,2,3})

184 ns ± 2.08 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit {1,2}.issubset({1,2,3})
120 ns ± 0.607 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

You can also pass the `terms` dataframe in the function, so that the interpreter doesn't need to look for it out of the function scope, and maybe you can use the `pd.Series.sum()` function instead of calling the Python one (this also should speed things up).

```
def search(g1, g2, terms):
    # search gene pair in the go terms
    return terms.gene_set.map({g1,g2}.issubset).sum()
```

Aside that, you could try the `df.apply()` method using [Polars](https://www.pola.rs/) or [Dask](https://www.dask.org/) for more substantial speed-ups.

Answer (score 1):

What if you `.explode` the smaller terms dataframe to get rid of the sets.

```
long_terms = terms.explode('gene_set')
```

```
>>> long_terms
   id gene_set
0   1     BCL6
0   1    HDAC4
1   2     BCL6
1   2    HDAC5
2   3    HDAC7
2   3     BCL6
3   4    KAT2B
3   4   CREBBP
3   4    NCOA3
3   4    EP300
4   5     SMC2
4   5    NCAPH
4   5     SMC4
4   5   NCAPD2
4   5    NCAPG
5   6  ATF7IP2
5   6        A
6   7     PIGB
6   7        B
7   8     PIGB
7   8        C
7   8  ATF7IP2
```

You can then use `.isin`

```
same_row = (
   long_terms.gene_set.isin(df.gene1).groupby(level=0).any()
   &
   long_terms.gene_set.isin(df.gene2).groupby(level=0).any()
)

found = long_terms.loc[same_row]
```

```
>>> found
   id gene_set
7   8     PIGB
7   8        C
7   8  ATF7IP2
```

To find the corresponding match:

```
>>> df.gene1.isin(found.gene_set) & df.gene2.isin(found.gene_set)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

```
>>> df[df.gene1.isin(found.gene_set) & df.gene2.isin(found.gene_set)]
  gene1    gene2     score
1  PIGB  ATF7IP2 -0.047236
```

Sample used:

```
>>> df
  gene1    gene2     score
0  PIGA  ATF7IP1 -0.047236
1  PIGB  ATF7IP2 -0.047236
2  PIGC  ATF7IP3 -0.047236
3  PIGD  ATF7IP4 -0.047236
4  PIGE  ATF7IP5 -0.047236
```

```
>>> terms
   id                            gene_set
0   1                       {BCL6, HDAC4}
1   2                       {BCL6, HDAC5}
2   3                       {HDAC7, BCL6}
3   4       {KAT2B, CREBBP, NCOA3, EP300}
4   5  {SMC2, NCAPH, SMC4, NCAPD2, NCAPG}
5   6                        {ATF7IP2, A}
6   7                           {PIGB, B}
7   8                  {PIGB, C, ATF7IP2}
```

```
terms = pd.DataFrame({
   "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
   "gene_set": [
      {"HDAC4", "BCL6"},
      {"HDAC5", "BCL6"},
      {"HDAC7", "BCL6"},
      {"NCOA3", "KAT2B", "EP300", "CREBBP"},
      {"NCAPD2", "NCAPH", "NCAPG", "SMC4", "SMC2"},
      {"A", "ATF7IP2"},
      {"B", "PIGB"},
      {"C", "ATF7IP2", "PIGB"},
   ]
})
```

Comment: gene-pairs supposed to be in the same row in terms data, otherwise It doesn't count as a matched pair.

Comment: @tyasird D'oh, silly me. I've added in extra steps you can use to ensure that constraint.